# Best practice for modular structure - Zend Framework 1?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to stack overflow, but I'm interested in everyone's opinion on this topic, I have attached a basic skeleton structure that I have created for my application, but I am unsure if it is best practice and am seeking advice :

```
application
    modules
        default
            controllers
                ErrorController
            Bootstrap
        posts
            controllers
                IndexController
                AdminController
                ApiController
            models
                Post
            Bootstrap
```

As you can see, I have separated the posts section of my application into a module of it's own, to me this makes sense as all of the code used within the post model / form etc will be re-useable for all of the controllers and it seems a really neat way to do things.

Another possible solution is the following :

```
application
    modules
        default
            controllers
                ErrorController
                PostsController
            models
                Post
            Bootstrap
        admin
            controllers
                PostsController
            models
                Post
            Bootstrap
        api
            controllers
                PostsController
            models
                Post
            Bootstrap
```

This is the way that people tend to set up a Zend Application? I have seen this several times across the internet, the only benefit I can see to this solution is the default routing would provide nice URLs, but for your code to be re-useable you would be cross referencing things from various modules and it doesn't seem as neat as the first solution.

If anyone could shed some light and explain why either is the best way to do things then that would be a huge help, thanks guys!

Comment: Why are you using ZF1??

Comment: Not my decision unfortunately, company policy, I'm also pushing for us to start using ZF2, I suppose this question could apply ZF2 also?

Comment: I don't know whether the same applies to ZF2 too. I only see that ZF1 will be discontinued soon (the official statement is early 2014) so choosing ZF1 sounds like a terrible idea to me :-) Is the company also forcing you to use PHP4? ;-)

Comment: Haha not quite, our selling point is that we are ZF certified engineers, such accreditation is not yet available for ZF2 as I'm sure you're aware :) , I would have thought that this question would have applied to most modular MVC frameworks, for example in cakePHP, would you have a Plugin called Admin with a post controller you would like to administrate or a Plugin called Post with an admin controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid approaches. My personal preference is the first option, since it keeps related classes together. The only issue is ensuring access restriction (and sensible URLs) on the admin controllers, since it's much easier to do this when they're all in an "admin" module.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, where in your opinion is best to put the routes for each module? Put all of the routes in the route application bootstrap file, or put routes in the module that concerns them? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Module's roots in the module bootstrap - keeps everything together. Any others in the main bootstrap